# Reasoning behind CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest in OSX/IOS

Tags: c++, ios, macos, cfnetwork, cfreadstream

I have recently written an asynchronous HTTP client in c++ for iOS/OSX. I was confused as to why headers were not arriving in my CFHTTPMessageRef response object until I realised that there was an object lurking as a property of the stream which contains the headers (after handling the kCFStreamEventBytesAvailable event).

So now I copy the headers from the property into my response object during the notification of the stream ending, before calling my event handler.

(code available on request, there's quite a lot of it)

The Apple documentation is characteristically silent on the subject and I was wondering if anyone out there knows the reason for this design decision by apple. I am keen to know in case I have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere?

EDIT: the documentation says this:

> After you schedule the request on a run loop, you will eventually get
>   a header complete callback. At this point, you can call
>   CFReadStreamCopyProperty to get the message response from the read
>   stream

However there seems to be no indication as to what the name or value of this event mask is.

EDIT:
Having done some experimenting, I see that the stream creates its own response object some time after sending the `kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted` notification and before the first `kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` notification.

In the `kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` event handler I can do this:

```
auto response = (CFHTTPMessageRef)CFReadStreamCopyProperty(readStream,
                                          kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader);
constexpr CFIndex bufferSize = 1024;
UInt8 buffer[bufferSize];
auto bytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(readStream, buffer, bufferSize);
if (bytesRead > 0) {
    CFHTTPMessageAppendBytes(response, buffer, bytesRead);
}
CFRelease(response);
```

and the stream's response message object is indeed updated with new body data.
Now I am curious as to why this is not just done automatically by the stream?